# Get sub from cognito user in amazon webservices

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I sign up a new user in the cognito in AWS. Here is the code (JavaScript):

```
userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
     cognitoUser = result.user;
     console.log("cognitoUser: ", cognitoUser);
});
```

My question is: **How get I get the sub from the new user?**
`cognitoUser` just contains the username. I didn't find any method for it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: [adminGetUser()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property)

You should call this message in a lambda function.

Probably you will get the error message that you are not authorized. So, you must add `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoPowerUser` to your iotSam.yaml.

Now, it should work.